# Google tag manager not running when button click pops up alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, google-tag-manager

I need to track some content on a website using google tag manager. I'm fairy new to this so any help will be appreciated.

I have a button as per below:

```
<input type="button" name="purchase" id="btnPurchase" value="Buy now">
```

When this button is clicked it changes to this:

```
<input type="button" name="purchase" id="btnPurchase" value="Confirm" class="active">
```

When clicked again a popup will appear with some details of what you have purchased.

In the website there is the following wrapper which remains empty until `Confirm` is clicked:

```
<div class="purchaseWrapper" id="purchaseWrapper"> <img class="closeButton" src="images/pur-close.png" width="24" height="24">
    <div class="purchaseContainer" id="purchaseContainer"></div>
</div>
```

That `div` will be altered upon `Confirm` click and a `Javascript` alert box will show the content.

When clicking the button, the page does not refresh at all, it's all done through `Javascript` and `Ajax`.

We are having issues where google tag manager is not running a function to get data from the container. This would possibly be because the DOM has not been updated yet by a response from the server. So in other words at the time that the button is clicked and google tag manager runs, that container is still empty.

We just used a `Click` trigger checking for the button `id` and that the `class` is `active`.

Is there any way we can delay when the custom variable is run after the button is clicked? Or perhaps a better trigger we can use? Maybe a trigger that picks up that an alert has popped up?

Comment: Maybe try adding a delay function in your custom variable?

Answer (score 0):

> We just used a Click trigger checking for the button id and that the class is active.
>
> Is there any way we can delay when the custom variable is run after
>   the button is clicked? Or perhaps a better trigger we can use? Maybe a
>   trigger that picks up that an alert has popped up?

I ran into a similar problem when I needed to custom JS variable to execute after a button click. I found two solutions both require using a custom HTML tag.

So I used a custom HTML tag to execute a javascript function on button click. So I did;

```
$("#button").onclick(function(){

      // Insert code here
      // Execute variable here

})
```

Another option is to use a custom event as a trigger. One issue is when I had to use a different trigger because the marcos in GTM executed to quickly. So what I did is use a custom HTML tag. And I then pushed a variable into the dataLayer after a function executes.

What I needed was to collect a value on button click but the GTM tag fires before I can collect the value using custom code. So what I did is use a custom event. Like this

```
function executeCode (){
   var collect = $("div").text();
   dataLayer.push('collectEvent':collect);
   dataLayer.push('event':'varaibleCollect');
} executeCode();
```

So what I did is tie my tag to fire when the custom event trigger "variableCollect" is pushed into the dataLayer. So my variable collect will be in the dataLayer.

Comment: The only problem is that we are not allowed to alter the site at all so we have to use what is already there.

Comment: can you use a custom HTML tag with GTM to add some javascript code on the page?

Comment: I will have a look at this when I'm back to work and see.

Comment: @ShaneVanWyk how did it go?